# asp dot net BeginForm post method send nothing to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to have a form on the webpage /create. This form contains : name, description and price. When filled in, it should send the data to the controller.

De controller does not receive the data and I don't know why.

I tried deleting the pages and recreate them, this did not work. I also tried @html.textlabelfor. this also did not work.

Here is my view code :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Beheer", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Fill article name" name="Naam">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="des">Description:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Fill in article description" name="Omschrijving">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">Price:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Fill in article price" name="Prijs">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="submit" />
}
```

Here is my controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(ArtikelModel artikelModel)
    {
        return View(artikelModel);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Here is my model :

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public string Omschrijving { get; set; }
    public decimal Prijs { get; set; }
    public byte[] Foto { get; set; }
    public decimal Korting { get; set; }
    public List<ReviewModel> Reviews { get; set; }
```

I expected the ArtikelModel to be filled with data the user put it.

Comment: Does your controller method get called and your ArtikelModel is empty? Or does the controller method not get called at all? If you use developer tools in your browser, what do the form values look like?

Comment: as i tried its working fine your code is also correct there is not any issue. ArtikelModel  is null you got in your controller ?

Comment: At first sight, since you don't pass ALL properties of your model and they are not nullable, I guess the mapping can't be done and your controller doesn't get an "Artikel" object.

Also, I'd advise against using your native language to name your parameters, but that's more of a style guide than anything else.

Comment: Please show us the payload being POSTed to the server (from Chrome or Firefox developer tools, Network tab).

Comment: @G_P The controller method does not get called at all...

Comment: @DoctorPrisme Do I really have to pass all the properties? I don't want to actually

Comment: @LaljiDhameliya The controller method won't be called at all

Comment: @mjwills What do you mean?

Comment: your controller name is BeheerController right ?

Comment: @TheProgrammer : then use a view model : you create a model containing only the properties you will pass, and you say to your controller that he will receive that view model.

Then you build your real model from the view model.

So for instance here, you will have :

    ArtikelCreationModel{
        string naam,
        string omschrijving,
        int prijs
    }

and you will create an Artikel from that.

Comment: as i tried https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD12P.jpg and controller method  https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2RJ4.png

Comment: @DoctorPrisme oh okay that is a nice solution

Comment: @LaljiDhameliya Ok it works me also... I'm stupid. I did not start the application somehow?? I don't know how. Probably I started without debugging -_-

Comment: @DoctorPrisme If I make a View model from Artikel, I need to pass that to the Logic layer. In the logic layer I pass that View Model to the Data access layer. The problem is... my View layer can't talk to the Data access layer

Comment: @TheProgrammer : You need to review your architecture.

From the controler, you call a service (which is just a middleware class that will do the needed transformations on your view model).
From the service, you call a repository (which is, against, just a middleware class  that will do the required operations to save your model in the persisting layer.)

This way, your viewmodel doesn't reach the data layer, and your logic operations are out of the controler, and everything is cleanly separated and testable.

Comment: @DoctorPrisme I still do not understand it, if I would make a new class (ArticleViewModel) and put this in the "Views" folder. Then say in the controller : article.CreateArticle(ArticleViewModel). I pass the view model as parameter right?

article is in my logic layer btw.

Then in my logic layer I have a method that calls the "Insert" method from the database layer. So I have to pass the object (ArticleVIewModel) I think. But this is not possible because I do not want to make a reference between the Presentation layer and the Data access Layer.
I hope u understand :) What should I do

Comment: Controller -> receives input from user, pass it to the service, return result if there's one.
Controller.Create(ArticleViewModel model){
        service.Create(model)
    }

Service -> receives data that must be handled, applies required transformation, pass it to Repository for persisting.

service.Create(ArticleViewModel model){
    Article newArticle = new Article(model);
    repository.InsertOrUpdate(newArticle);
}

Repository -> saves/retrieves data in/from whatever is used as a database. 

Your presentation layer is separated of the DAL by the logic layer, aka the service

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicated that the controller method doesn't get called at all, the likely issue is the name of your controller as @LaljiDhameliya mentioned. So, since your view lists "Beheer" as the controller, due to ASP.NET MVC convention, your controller should be called "BeheerController" (you didn't include this bit of code in your question, so we can't see if that is the case)